# Mic volume much lower when joining a Discord live stream

Tags: windows-10, audio, discord

Whenever I join a Discord live stream, my mic volume when speaking while watching the stream will drop to a much lower level to the point where it can barely be heard by other people.

It happens regardless of whether or not I have earbuds plugged in. Not sure what else I can try to fix the situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to occur when you are either live streaming yourself *or* viewing a live stream. It also appears to be independent of your hardware (which you observed when you switched to your earbuds and continued to have issues.) The problem appears to be purely Discord's.

Some configuration that eliminated the problem for me was heading into **Settings**, opening up **Voice & Audio**, scrolling down to the **Advanced** section, and making sure that...

1. **Noise Suppression** is off.
2. In the Voice Processing section, **Noise Reduction** is off.

After disabling these two settings, my audio appeared to come through as clear as though I wasn't watching a live stream. I also started a livestream myself and had others join, and I sounded perfectly fine to other users.

Comment: Tried this, tried turning on Legacy audio subsystem, everything - to no avail at all. I've been through the whole pandemic and the only workaround I ever got was using the web app, which is next to unacceptable. Will Discord just fix this already?

Comment: Yeah this solution appears to only work for a few people I know. Others are still struggling, like yourself. Discord really does need to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating Echo cancellation did it for me. I think that should work for most.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Blows my mind that this is causing it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different fix on my side.  Although I had attenuation set to 0%, I still had the flag for attenuation for "when others speak" set to true.  I figured this didn't do anything due to the tooltip above, but once I turned that flag off my issue got resolved.